# How can I get all possible paths to traverse the tree?

Tags: javascript, tree

The question is: How can I get an array of all tree paths?

In this example there are 5 ways:

```
[
  [{ 1: "2" }, { 3: "4" }],
  [{ 1: "2" }, { 3: "5" }],
  [{ 1: "6" }, { 7: "8" }],
  [{ 1: "6" }, { 7: "9" }, { 10: "11" }],
  [{ 1: "6" }, { 7: "9" }, { 10: "12" }],
]
```

[image]

I can loop through all nested objects with recursion, but I don't know how to get that array...

Here is my code:

```
const data = {
  "1": {
    "2": {
      "3": {
        "4": {},
        "5": {}
      }
    },
    "6": {
      "7": {
        "8": {},
        "9": {
          "10": {
            "11": {},
            "12": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

let list = [];

function iterate(object) {
    if( object !== null && typeof object == "object" ) {
        Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if( JSON.stringify(value) != JSON.stringify({})) {
                let obj = {};
                obj[key] = Object.keys(value)
                list.push(obj);
                iterate(value);
            }
        });
    }
}

iterate(data);
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `[{ 1: "2" }, { 3: "4/5" }]` one path and not two `[{ 1: "2" }, { 3: "4" }], [{ 1: "2" }, { 3: "5" }]`? Where is `{ 2: "3" }`? The tree has 5 leaves. I would expect 5 paths. Please read the tag description before you use a tag. The JSON tag description contains: _Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals._ There is no JSON in this question.

Comment: Your example has only paths with an even number of nodes. What if a path has an odd number of nodes? How would you represent that? It is a strange format you are looking for, and I can only see disadvantages for it, no advantages. I would expect a path to be an array of labels, like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, and the whole set of paths to look like `[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,6,7,8],[1,6,7,9,10,11],[1,6,7,9,10,12]]`.

Comment: The task i'm trying to do has only an even number of nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a recursive function that will iterate the paths in a more intuitive format: each path will be represented as an array of nodes. This function could be a generator function.

Then create a *mapping* function that converts such path to a list of objects with single key/value pairs, assuming the given path has an even number of nodes.

Finally, use `Array.from` to consume the iterator returned by the generator function, and use the mapping argument to perform the mapping defined by the second function:

```js
function* iteratePaths(object) {
    const entries = Object.entries(Object(object));
    if (entries.length == 0) return yield [];
    for (const [key, value] of entries) {
        for (const path of iteratePaths(value)) {
            yield [key, ...path];
        }
    }
}

const toPairs = path => 
    path.reduce((acc, val, i) => i % 2 ? [...acc, { [path[i-1]]: val }] : acc, []);

// Example input:
const data = {"1": {"2": {"3": {"4": {},"5": {}}},"6": {"7": {"8": {},"9": {"10": {"11": {},"12": {}}}}}}}
const result = Array.from(iteratePaths(data), toPairs);
console.log(result);
```